# WSL Flatpak Run Gnome Web Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: wsl-2, flatpak

I have installed app GWSL from Windows Store to run gui apps and it works for apps I got from apt. When I wanted to use GNOME Web I had to install it using Flatpak and when I try to run it

```
flatpak run org.gnome.Epiphany
```

I get error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

I have installed XFCE4 and connected using remote desktop and I still get the same error so I don't think the cause of the error is GWSL app. Does enyone have suggetion how to resolve this problem? We wanted to use GNOME Web for testing. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I had a similar problem that was solved enabling systemd on WSL2.